# variable inside a subprocess.call in python

Tags: python

I want to insert a variable in place of the ip address
this is my working code without the variable:

```
subprocess.call(r'net use T: \\192.168.1.10\myshare /PERSISTENT:YES', shell=True)
```

this is my not workings attempts with the variable:

```
myip = "192.168.1.10"
subprocess.call(r'net use T: \\'+myip'\myshare /PERSISTENT:YES', shell=True)

#or:
subprocess.call(r'net use T: \\', 'myip', '\myshare /PERSISTENT:YES', shell=True)

#or:
subprocess.call(r'net use T: \\'+myip+'\myshare /PERSISTENT:YES', shell=True)

#or:
subprocess.call(r'net use T: \\+myip+\myshare /PERSISTENT:YES', shell=True)
```

none of these works
any suggestions?

Comment: Your third example (`subprocess.call(r'net use T: \\'+myip+'\myshare /PERSISTENT:YES', shell=True)`) should have worked.  Did you get any error message?

Comment: The second substring also has backslashes and needs the `r` prefix.

Answer (score 1):

You need the raw prefix on any substring that has backslashes:

```
subprocess.call(r'net use T: \\'+myip+r'\myshare /PERSISTENT:YES', shell=True)
```

Or:

```
subprocess.call(
   ['net', 'use', rf'\\{myip}\myshare', '/PERSISTENT:YES'],
   shell=True
)
```